# eloquent: query many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I create many to many relationship between users and roles like this:

User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Role model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

my question is how I can get only users that belongs to some specific role name, for example if I have a role name called "author", I want to get all author users, something like this in sql:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users, roles, role_user 
WHERE users.id = role_user.user_id
AND role_user.role_id = roles.id
AND roles.name="author";
```

note: I'm using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Role::with(array('user'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','name');
    }))
   ->where('role_name', 'author')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($query){
   $query->where('role_name', 'author')
})
->get(['name', 'id']);
```

You may change column name for table `role`, I have used `role_name`,

Now this should work, it will retrieve name and id for users only with at least one role

Comment: thanks @GauravRai, i need to select only user id and name not all fields, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Updated answer, have  a look

Comment: How to check not in following your answer? @Gaurav Rai

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following code:

```
$userRoles = Role::where('name', 'author')->with('users')->get();
$userRoles->users->id;
$userRoles->users->name;
```

or

```
$userRoles = Role::select('users.id, users.name')->where('name', 'author')->with('users')->get();
```